# Perl regular expression mismatches repetitive strings

Tags: regex, perl, mismatch

I am trying to match *at least* four G-repeats, each repeat separated by a maximum of 7 characters. Example:

```
AAGGGAAGGGAAAGGGAAGGGAA
```

I use following regex which should match uppercase and lowercase characters.

```
$sequence =~ /((G{3,}[ATGC]{1,7}){3,}G{3,})/gi
```

This should match at least four G-repeats. The problem is, that I get a positive hit when I match the following sequence:

```
aaagaggaaaaggggaaaaggggaaaaggggaaa
```

The first repeat in this sequence contains three gs, separated by an a. Therefore, this sequence should not be matched.

Solution 1: The problem seemed to be the /i modifier. I could correct it by modifying the regex:

```
 $sequence =~ /(([gG]{3,}[aAtTgGcC]{1,7}){3,}[gG]{3,})/g
```

Solution 2 provided by ikegami: Negative lookahead.

```
$sequence =~ /(([?!G]{3,}[ATGC]{1,7}){3,}[G]{3,})/gi
```

Thanks @ikegami for the hint and for submitting the bug report.

Comment: There [doesn't seem to be](https://regex101.com/r/osA53E/1) a positive hit on the second sequence.

Comment: @Nicolas Maltais, The OP is using Perl, not PCRE.

Comment: If you want to match at least 4 G's, why does  the quantifier start at 3? See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions

Comment: @shawnhcorey: I want to match at least 4 G-repeats, with at least 3 Gs each.

Comment: @Zipfer So, you need to match 4 patterns of 3 or more G's. That clarifies things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ perl -E'say $& while "aaagaggaaaaggggaaaaggggaaaaggggaaa" =~ /((G{3,}[ATGC]{1,7}){3,}G{3,})/gi'
gggaaaaggggaaaagggg
```

You've found a bug! I filed a [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130307).

This bug has been around since at least since 5.10, and it's present in the latest release (5.24.0).

Update: Fixed in Perl 5.26, released on 2017-05-30.

Comment: I need a G in [ATGC], because the interconnecting sequence could be aaagaaa.

Comment: Why negative lookahead? When the regex matches a G that follows the GGG, it is recognized as GGGG, which must be followed by a [ATC]. If the GGG is followed by AG, the regex works.

Comment: That's right, works as well. When I add the ?! to the G{3} and at the same time use the /i modifier, the regex doesn't match `gaggaaagggaaagggaaaggg`. But when I match `([gG]{3}[aAcCgGtT]...` the regex doesn't recognize `gaggaaaggg...` anymore.

Comment: 5.26 (which fixes this bug) was released today